# Delete single character rows in a text file

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

I have a text file with about 8 million rows in it. I need to remove all the rows with a single character in them. For example

```
This is 
the 
text file 
I 
wrote
```

I want to remove the entire line that has the pronoun "I" on it. Bonus points to the one who can do this on the linux command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
awk 'length>1' file
```

and if you do not want to delete blank lines (with zero characters)

```
awk 'length!=1' file
```

And if you have spaces on the lines (that you do not want to count as characters):

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")}length!=1' file
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and @pfnuesel for the quick reply. I went with awk 'length>1' file > newfile and it works like a champ!

Answer (score 5):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can do that as well:

```
sed '/^.$/d' inputFile
```

To store the output in a new file:

```
sed '/^.$/d' inputFile > outputFile
```

or for in-file editing:

```
sed -i '/^.$/d' inputFile
```

Comment: Thanks! I really can't tell the difference in performance so I am simply going to choose the tool based on alphabetical order. A before S :)

Comment: @AdamEstrada going forward, you should choose the tool designed for the job at hand. `grep` is for finding REs and printing the result (named based on the `ed` command G/RE/P), `sed` is for replacing REs on a single line (Stream ED), `awk` is for every other text manipulation.

Comment: @EdMorton I completely agree and am compiling a cheat sheet of all these tips to help me out in the future.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is:

```
grep '..' file
```

unless you want to keep empty lines as well in which case it'd be:

```
grep -v '^.$' file
```

Comment: So simple.. Great one !

Answer (score 0):

Done by shell

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

while read line
do
   if [[ "${#line}" != 1 ]]; then
       echo $line
   fi
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

bash

```
 while read -r line
 do 
     if [ ${#line} -gt 1 ] ;then    
        echo $line 
     fi
 done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ruby on your system

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_ if $_.chomp.length >1 ' file
```